# Is it possible to apply different CSS properties to tags that have no id and class?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out if I can apply different CSS to tags that don't have a class. The example I posted in the snippet obviously doesn't work, but my question is: how can I apply different CSS to the two spans without a class or id?

```css
.box {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.box > span 1  {
font-size: 28px;
}

.box > span 2  {
font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">
   <span>Example 1</span>
   <span>Example 2</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class:

```
.box span:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.box span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` if you know there will always be two.

Answer (score 1):

For your example you can also use:

```css
.box span:first-of-type {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.box span:last-of-type {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Be sure to take a look at [All CSS Pseudo Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp#:%7E:text=all%20css%20pseudo%20classes).

Comment: Thanks, it works. However I prefer to number with nth: child as it is likely that I will not have only two elements (first and last). I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @Snorlax You can also use [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: What is the difference with `:nth-child()` ?